Get records that have total count of over X amount
I have a VIEW that looks like this:
| email  | list  | sent_last_30_days |
--------------------------------------
| email1 | list1 |       1           |
| email2 | list1 |       0           |
| email1 | list2 |       1           |
| email3 | list3 |       1           |
| email1 | list3 |       1           |
| email2 | list2 |       0           |
| email1 | list4 |       0           |
| email2 | list3 |       1           |
--------------------------------------

If you take note of email1, it is found on 4 lists but only active on 3 (as indicated by the 1 or 0 in the sent_last_30_days column).
email2 is found on 3 lists, but only active on 1.
I need to write a query that will return the records that are active on 3 or more lists.
Using the example above, email1 will be the only records that will return.
So the results of said query will look something like this:
| email  | list  | sent_last_30_days |
--------------------------------------
| email1 | list1 |       1           |
| email1 | list2 |       1           |
| email1 | list3 |       1           |
| email1 | list4 |       0           |
--------------------------------------

Because email1 has been active on at least 3 lists.
email2 and email3 did not meet this requirement because they weren't active on at least 3 lists.
MySQL version: 5.7.44

Can you please query SELECT VERSION(); to confirm exactly what version of MySQL you are using? Window functions could be the solution, if you are using MySQL 8.x or later.

Looks like it's version 5.7.44

Thanks for checking. Unfortunately, window functions are not supported in MySQL 5.x.

Hey John, be aware: 5.7 releases have been fully out of support for coming up on a year. That means no updates in that time... not even critical security patches. It's also based on a platform that (effectively) traces back to 2004. That series pretty much stagnated since the Oracle acquisition. It's missing so many features I wouldn't even qualify it as a modern database engine. It's really long past time to upgrade this application.

Have you tried anything???

Well, let's find email which are active in at least 3 distinct lists (e.g. list1, list2, list3 for email1):
  select mv.email                         
    from MyView mv
   where mv.sent_last_30_days <> 0       -- only active
group by mv.email                        
  having count(distinct mv.list) >= 3    -- having at least 3 distinct lists

having this subquery we can add it into where of the main query:
  select *
    from MyView
   where email in (select mv.email
                     from MyView mv
                    where mv.sent_last_30_days <> 0
                 group by mv.email
                   having count(distinct mv.list) >= 3)

Drop distinct if an email should appear in any 3 lists, doesn't necessary distinct (e.g. list1, list1, list2)

This will work! And it's the way I would have done it until about a year and a half ago. But today, windowing functions are likely MUCH more efficient.

Oh, and windowing functions have been available for longer than a year and a half, but they also take time to adopt into one's workflow, so there's also no shame in doing this the old way!

@Joel Coehoorn:I absolutely agree about window functions, but when facing MySQL of a unknown version I stick to good old SQL-92 to be on the safer side ;)

Using this example appears to work, however, in the inner select, where it reads "mv.sent_last_30_days <> 0".  That mean the only records that should come back are the ones with a 1 in that column.  Right?  Because I am still getting the NULL and 0 records.  Does that make sense?

Try this:
WITH ListCounts AS
(
    select *
     , sum(case when sent_last_30_days > 0 then 1 end) over (partition by email) ListCount
    from MyView
)
SELECT email, list, sent_last_30_days
FROM ListCounts
WHERE ListCount >= 3

See it work here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/u8s1R8iT


OP is using 5.7.44 version , which doesn't support window functions. Note that some old systems still are using old MySQL version

In MySQL, you can simply write sum(sent_last_30_days > 0) without the case expression.

You can use EXISTS(corelated subquery) to filter data:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
    list_data ( email, list, sent_last_30_days ) AS
      ( Select 'email1', 'list1', 1 Union All 
        Select 'email2', 'list1', 0 Union All 
        Select 'email1', 'list2', 1 Union All 
        Select 'email3', 'list3', 1 Union All 
        Select 'email1', 'list3', 1 Union All 
        Select 'email2', 'list2', 0 Union All 
        Select 'email1', 'list4', 0 Union All 
        Select 'email2', 'list3', 1 
     )

--    S Q L : 
Select  l.*
From    list_data l
Where   Exists( Select 1 
                From list_data 
                Where email = l.email And sent_last_30_days = 1 
                Group By email
                Having Count(list) >= 3 )

/*    R e s u l t :
email   list    sent_last_30_days
------  ------  -----------------
email1  list1                   1
email1  list2                   1
email1  list3                   1
email1  list4                   0      */

See the fiddle here.
